# Convert column pairwise individual row data to correlation matrix

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matrix, correlation

I'm trying to convert my z scores (axa),(axb) values as shown below to a correlation matrix.

[image]

The individual row correlation matrix of the first row as shown below:

[image]

Are there any way I can transform my csv easily in python? After tranformation I should be able to do:

```
import pandas as pd
con = pd.read_csv('Data/connectivity.csv')
# Do transform here
cormat = con.corr()
round(cormat,2)
sns.heatmap(cormat);
```

Thank you.

Kevin

EDIT

Sorry for the edit so I forgot to mention I was going to create only one connectivity matrix (correlation matrix) by taking the average of in this example the 4 rows.

so have to do a:

```
import pandas as pd
con = pd.read_csv('Data/connectivity.csv')
con_average = con.mean()
tmp = con_average.set_axis(df.columns.str.split(' vs ',expand=True))
out = tmp.iloc[0].unstack()
```

Comment: Please don't use images of code/data, instead provide a [reproducible input](/q/20109391/16343464). What is the output of `con.to_dict('tight')` (as [edit] to your question)

Comment: You have not described your "transformation" correctly, above. The input holds 4 (!) records of a 3x3 matrix (unstacked into 9 columns), whereas your desired output shows a 3x3 matrix for only a single record... That transformation makes no sense. What exactly do you expect? A list with 4 different `df` instances (one per input row)? Or a 3-dimensional df (transforming from 4x9 to 3x3x4, with a MultiIndex)? Or only one `df` that holds the csv's data of the first row (as shown in your screenshot)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this input:

```
   a x a     a x b     a x c     b x a  b x b    b x c    c x a    c x b  c x c
0      1  0.315900    0.5391  0.315900      1  0.45100  0.53910  0.45100      1
1      1  0.387880   0.30813  0.387880      1  0.33133  0.30813  0.33133      1
2      1 -0.021537  -0.30658 -0.021537      1  0.68163 -0.30658  0.68163      1
3      1 -0.001746   0.11458 -0.001746      1  0.39171  0.11458  0.39171      1
```

You can first [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) the column names into a MultiIndex:

```
tmp = df.set_axis(df.columns.str.split(' x ', expand=True), axis=1)
```

Then, if you want to build your matrix from the **first row**, slice it and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
out = tmp.iloc[0].unstack()
```

Output:

```
        a       b       c
a       1  0.3159  0.5391
b  0.3159       1   0.451
c  0.5391   0.451       1
```

To build a new dataframe **for each row**, either loop:

```
dfs = [tmp.iloc[i].unstack() for i in range(tmp.shape[0])]
```

Or first [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) then split with [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
dfs = [g for _, g in tmp.stack().groupby(level=0)]
```

Output:

```
[          a       b       c
 0 a       1  0.3159  0.5391
   b  0.3159  1.0000  0.4510
   c  0.5391  0.4510  1.0000,
             a        b        c
 1 a         1  0.38788  0.30813
   b   0.38788  1.00000  0.33133
   c  0.30813,  0.33133  1.00000,
             a         b        c
 2 a         1 -0.021537 -0.30658
   b -0.021537  1.000000  0.68163
   c  -0.30658  0.681630  1.00000,
             a         b        c
 3 a         1 -0.001746  0.11458
   b -0.001746  1.000000  0.39171
   c   0.11458  0.391710  1.00000]
```

If you want to average the rows:

```
out = (df.set_axis(df.columns.str.split(' x ', expand=True), axis=1)
         .mean().unstack()
      )
```

Output:

```
          a         b         c
a  1.000000  0.170124  0.163808
b  0.170124  1.000000  0.463917
c  0.163808  0.463917  1.000000
```

Intermediate `tmp`:

```
   a                             b                    c            
   a         b         c         a  b        c        a        b  c
0  1  0.315900    0.5391  0.315900  1  0.45100  0.53910  0.45100  1
1  1  0.387880   0.30813  0.387880  1  0.33133  0.30813  0.33133  1
2  1 -0.021537  -0.30658 -0.021537  1  0.68163 -0.30658  0.68163  1
3  1 -0.001746   0.11458 -0.001746  1  0.39171  0.11458  0.39171  1
```

Comment: Hi sorry about this. I was going to average the 4 rows and then do a correlation as above. out = tmp.iloc[0].unstack() gives me 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'unstack'.

Comment: Make sure to run `tmp = df.set_axis(df.columns.str.split(' x ', expand=True), axis=1)`. If you want to average all rows, use `tmp.mean().unstack()`

Comment: Hi if my current quick code is **import pandas as pd,
df = pd.read_csv('hv.csv'), df_average = df.mean(), tmp = df_average.set_axis(df.columns.str.split(' vs ', expand=True)), out = tmp.mean().unstack()** if I try tmp = df_average.set_axis(df.columns.str.split(' x ', expand=True), axis=1) it chokes as I only have one row.  Not setting the axis as above gives me AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'unstack'

Comment: Well, you already averaged, just use `pd.read_csv('hv.csv')`, skip the averaging and then `df.set_axis(df.columns.str.split(' x ', expand=True), axis=1).mean().unstack()`

Comment: or `df_average.set_axis(df_average.index.str.split(' vs ', expand=True)).unstack()`